# Intranet DNS Name

Tags: domain-name-system, intranet

We are using Windows Server 2003 in a small environment with its own domain setup. The company intranet is currently http://ServerName (the server running IIS). How do I change this so instead of having the servername in the address field, people can type in "intranet" or another name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a CNAME record to your internal DNS with the name intranet pointing to ServerName.yourdomain.local (or whatever your DNS domain name is).

Comment: So, in DNS. I open the Forward Lookup Zone and right click for a new Alias. What do I put in the 'CNAME' and 'Fully qualified domain name'?

Comment: Also once it is in and set, how long until it replicates? Thank you.

Comment: Usually, only a reboot of computer will update the DNS records. You can also run "ipconfig /flushdns" on your client to ensure they got the lastest DNS Records in cache.

Comment: It should replicate to all the DNS servers in that site within a minute or so.  If you have more than one site it'll take a little longer.  At least 15 minutes (or longer depending on what your site to site replication settings are).

Comment: Are you still waiting for an answer on your first question? If so, under 'CNAME' you will enter 'intranet' and under FQDN you enter 'servername.mydomain.local' (or whatever the full path to your server is)